# How to remove empty directories with Python 3 using map() and filter() functions instead of for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, delete-directory

I'm trying to create a function with Python 3 that deletes empty directories in a specified directory.

Unfortunately, my attempts haven't been successful, so I'd appreciate any help, guidance, and suggestions.

#### Example of what I'm trying to get the function to do:

Before...

```
-folder/
    |-empty1/
    |-empty2/
    |-not_empty1/
        |-file
    |-not_empty2/
        |-file
```

After...

```
-folder/
    |-not_empty1/
        |-file
    |-not_empty2/
        |-file
```

### Here's what I was sure would work but didn't:

```
# folder - absolute path to directory that may contain empty directories
def cleanup(folder):
    from os import listdir, rmdir, path
    ls = listdir(folder)
    ls = map(lambda f: path.join(folder, f), ls)
    folders = filter(lambda f: path.isdir(f), ls)
    map(lambda x: rmdir(x), folders)
```

Thanks!

EDITS:

1. Removed extra parenthesis at the end that the first map had from using `list(map(...))` to debug with `print` statements
2. Moved `path.join()` line above `path.isdir()`
3. Changed the title of the question from "...Python 3 in FP style" since, as pointed out in the comments, this isn't a correct implementation and application of FP.

Comment: This can't be your real code.  The `map()` line has too many right-parentheses.

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. What do you consider to be a _functional programming style_, and why use it for this?

Comment: `filter()` produces empty results, because you're calling `isdir(f)` without including the original parent folder.

Comment: Functional programming is about manipulating immutable data with functions. Deleting directories is an inherently stateful task that involves issuing a command to the OS. While you can certainly shoehorn anything into FP style, this really won't be a good use of it.

Comment: _"Here's what I was sure would work but didn't"_ - why/how are you sure when there isn't even a check for emptiness prior to removing a folder?

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon for catching those 2 mistakes

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I was just experimenting and your input is definitely helpful to consider this a failed experiment. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.rmdir` only removes empty directories, so there’s nothing left to do in a functional style in a correct and minimal implementation:

```py
import errno
import os


def cleanup(folder):
    for name in os.listdir(folder):
        try:
            os.rmdir(os.path.join(folder, name))
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ENOTEMPTY:
                raise
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this minimal solution